# Is there an emotional equivalent of Somatoparaphrenia?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, psychiatry

I've recently became aware of the [Somatoparaphrenia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatoparaphrenia) delusion, where a person thinks that a part of their body belongs to someone else. No amount of logic or evidence would persuade that person otherwise. For example:

> This is not my leg, this is my fathers leg.

This makes me ask - **is there an emotional equivalent of Somatoparaphrenia, where a person pathologically projects some emotions into others and is unable to realize it is their own emotion?**

I'm aware of disorders like Narcissistic Personality Disorder, which has a tendency of projecting negative feelings into the world. But are there more severe cases?

Comment: Found this blog post that goes into a bit more detail. The term they use is "blame shifting", and mentions that it's common with the dark triad women http://illimitablemen.com/2014/12/14/the-shit-test-encyclopedia/

Comment: Found another term - "Enmeshment" in codependent relationships https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codependency#Enmeshed_romantic_relationship